# Find the list of all duplicate vertices with tolerance in a large array in Fortran

Tags: duplicates, fortran

I am trying to write an efficient subroutine in Fortran to find the list of all duplicate vertices in an array. The tolerance (fixed using parameter `paraEps`) corresponds to the radius around each point in which I look for the duplicate points. The vertices and defined for Finite Element Analysis and the range of each component will depend on the 3D geometry on which the methods will be applied (I can expect that values of the components could be varied in `[-10^6,10^6]` with a precision of `10^-6`.

Currently the following code is running on around 150k vertices but it will be used on array of 1-3M vertices.

**Example:**

A array of vertices. Here I just use some small list of nodes. In my case, nodes are in a 3D space with no specific distribution.

```
 verticesArray = 
[ 0 0 0,
  0 1 0
  1 0 0
  1 0 0
  1 1 1
  0 1 0
  1 2 3
  1 2 3
  0 1.0001 0
  0 1.1 0
  1 2 4]
```

The result list (0 means the vertice has no duplicate) with a tolerance of `10^-3`.

```
list = [ 0 1 2 2 0 1 3 3 1 0 0]
```

I have written a first version that works fine but remains slow especially the number of vertices is large.

Notice that `startItem` is an integer I can specify for starting the search not from the beginning of the array.

**MWE:**

```
module test 

implicit none

contains

subroutine get_dup_nodes(nbNodes,dimP,arrayIn,nbDupNodes)
    !
    integer,intent(in) :: nbNodes,dimP                      ! number of nodes and dimension
    double precision,dimension(:,:),intent(in) :: arrayIn   ! list of coordinates
    !
    integer,intent(out) :: nbDupNodes   
    !
    double precision,dimension(dimP) :: coorNode

    integer,dimension(:),allocatable :: listDup         !list of duplicates


    logical :: currUnique
    double precision,allocatable :: distVal
    integer :: itN,itM,itF,minCurrIt,currIt,nbTmp,sizeR,startItemVal
    !
    double precision,parameter :: paraEps=1e-3
    !

    !initialize variables
    allocate(listDup(nbNodes))
    listDup=0
    nbDupNodes=0
    itF=0
    distVal=1.
    !
    do itN=1,nbNodes
        !coordinate current node
        coorNode=arrayIn(itN,:)
        currUnique=.true.
        !search for current nodes coordinates in the list of nodes
        if (listDup(itN).eq.0) then
            do itM=itN+1,nbNodes
                ! compute distance to current point
                distVal = NORM2(coorNode-arrayIn(itM,:))
                ! if the distance is to small then duplicate
                if (distVal.le.paraEps) then
                    !first time it is a duplicate
                    if (currUnique) then
                        currUnique=.false.
                        nbDupNodes=nbDupNodes+1
                        listDup(itN)=nbDupNodes
                    endif
                    listDup(itM)=nbDupNodes
                endif
            enddo                
        endif
    enddo

    print *,listDup
end subroutine get_dup_nodes

end module test

program testb
use test
implicit none

double precision,dimension(33) :: valTmp
double precision,dimension(11,3) :: verticesArray
integer :: nbd

integer :: i,j,k

valTmp = (/ 0.,0.,0.,0.,1.,0.,1.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,1.,1.,1.,0.,1.,0.,1.,2.,3.,1.,2.,3.,0.,1.0001,0.,0.,1.1,0.,1.,2.,4. /)

k=1
do i=1,11
    do j=1,3
        verticesArray(i,j)=ValTmp(k)
        k=k+1
    enddo
    print *,verticesArray(i,:)
enddo

call get_dup_nodes(11,3,verticesArray,nbd)

end program testb
```

**Additional request:** if you have references of books about such kind of algorithm, it could be useful.

Comment: Also useful to know would be if the vertices are very roughly evenly distributed across the domain, or if they are very highly "clumped"

Comment: I just edited my post to add the requested information.

Comment: You haven't answered my question. If they are very roughly evenly distributed you may gain a lot of speed by dividing the domain into sub domains, having a first pass that lists which vertices are in each sub domain, and then you only need check that subdomain its neighbours for duplicate vertices - effectively reducing the length of your inner loop in your above example dramatically.

Comment: And BTW this isn't a MWE - a MWE is a complete program with sample input data where appropriate and the expected results. The above is just part of a subroutine.

Comment: @IanBush 1. I agree with your approach. Unfortunately, I have no assumption concerning the localization of the duplicate points in the domain; 2. I have improved my original post with a full fortran program.

Comment: Convert all the node coordinates by: (1) multiplying by `1/paraEps`; (2) adding `0.5*paraEps`; (3) truncating to integral values.  If my ciphering is correct all the nodes at the 'same' location will have the same integral locations.  (And if my ciphering isn't correct fix it or get a better idea.). Sort the list and then make a tally.

Comment: A sort of the data, or the index sorted, would be a good first step. Then using a logical mask the same size as the number of vertices.

Comment: I found an ambiguity in your definition of "duplicates" while trying to code a faster method for the search. Take the three nodes `A = [0, 0, 0]`, `B = [0, -0.0006, 0]`, and `C = [0, +0.0006, 0]`. According to your rule, A and B are duplicates, as are A and C. B and C are not. In other words, `A == B .and. A == C`, but `B /= C`.    The answer you get from your code depends on the order in which the nodes are in the array. Sometimes all three are considered equal, other times not.    How should these cases be interpreted? Do you want all three points to be duplicates of each other?